# My DataProvider is not getting called

Tags: java, testng

Hi I am using TestNG for testing on Eclipse indigo. I have set the DataProvider and its strange that control is skipping the DataProvider. Its executing @BeforeClass and @BeforeSuite and @AfterClass method.

Also its not throwing any error too.

Here's my code.

```
@DataProvider(name = "dpTest")
public Object dataProvider_test(java.lang.reflect.Method m) throws Exception{
    XLSReader xls = new XLSReader();
    return (xls.getDiscoveryEXCELData(sup.getDataSource(), "BOA Ad Position"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is not throwing any error probably points that you have not marked your test method to use the dataprovider.  In your annotation, you need to mark your test to use the dataProvider that you have written.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "dpTest")
```

Also, your return type of the dataProvider is Object, which is incorrect.  It should either be a Object[][] or Iterator[].